# How to rotate n-digits of a number without arrays?

Tags: c, loops

The problem: user inputs two numbers: a big one, and a small one.
The small number is the number of digits from the last number that will transfer into the front, and the remaining digits will follow.
For example: if the big number is `456789` and the small one is `3`, the result will be: `789456`.
my idea was as follows:

```
if (...) {
    newNum = BigNumber % (10 * SmallNumber);
    printf("%d", remainder");
    SmallNumber--; 
}
```

but it doesn't print in the order I was hoping for, digit by digit, and I can't understand why.
If using arrays would be allowed, it was no problem. Also I'm not allowed to use `string.length`, which also make it lots easier.

Comment: How big is the big number? Does it fit in an `int`? `long long`?

Comment: the number can be up to 9 digits long. and yeah, i used long long for it

Comment: Please, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

Rotating a number can be performed as a combination of cuts, shifts, and additions. For example, if you have a number `123456789` and you need to rotate it by `3`, you can do it as follows:

- Cut off the last three digits <s>123456</s>789
- Shift the remaining number by three digits to make 123456<s>789</s>
- Shift the last three digits by six to make `789000000`
- Add the two numbers together `789000000 + 123456` to get the result `789123456`.

Here is how you do these operations on decimal numbers:

- Cutting off the last `k` digits is done with modulo `%` 10<sup>k</sup>
- Shifting right by `k` digits is equivalent to integer division by 10<sup>k</sup>
- Shifting left by `k` digits is equivalent to multiplication by 10<sup>k</sup>
- Figuring out the number of significant digits in a number can be done by repeated integer division by ten.
- Addition is done the usual way.

Comment: And there is a need to find how many digits remain in the original number after cutting off the k lowest digits. Otherwise step 3 is unfeasible

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Right, I assumed OP already knew the repeated division trick.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Even though O(9) is the same as O(1), this can be done with a binary search in a look-up table of powers of ten in four comparisons.

Comment: Sure, since any type is bound; I meant in the general case. Lookup table is nice, although it's a bit of cheating - trading time complexity for space :)

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername You are right, trading something of lesser value (space) in return for something of significantly higher value (time) is very much like paying for gold with an equal amount of saw dust, so yes, it is a form of cheating. I'm glad it's legal, though :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think below code would help you -

```
//Here size = number of digits in bignumber-1
while(smallnumber--) {
   temp = (bignumber - bignumber%pow(10,size))/(pow(10,size);
   bignumber  = bignumber%pow(10,size);
   bignumber = bignumber*10 + temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
  long int num = 34234239;
  int swap = 5, other;
  long int rem = num % (int)(pow(10,swap)); /*The part that is shifted*/
  other = log10(num-rem)+1-swap; /*Length of the other part*/
  /* Result = (part to shift)*(Other part's length) + (Other part)*(Shifts) */
  num = rem*(int)pow(10,other) + (num-rem)/(int)pow(10,swap);
  printf("%ld\n",num);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try it with 3456789

Comment: I'll give you a hint - look at @dasblinkenlight answer. You got the correct answer only due to symmetric input

Answer (score 0):

I've accidentally stumbled upon how it works exactly the same way as trying to do bit-rotations in binary :

— *for readability purposes, most zeros in the outputs below have been replaced by the underscore* (`_`) *. Underscores in the `awk` code itself are variable names not zeros`

---

```
echo '123456789' | mawk2 '($++NF = 10^6 * $1 % (10^9 - 1))^_' 

123456789         
      789123456
```

---

```
jot -w '9876504321 %d' 11 0 | gawk -Mbe '($++NF = sprintf("%.*d",

     ___ = length(__ = $1), __ * 10^$2 % (10^___ - 1)))^_'

98765_4321   0   98765_4321
98765_4321   1   8765_43219
98765_4321   2   765_432198
98765_4321   3   65_4321987
98765_4321   4   5_43219876
98765_4321   5   _432198765
98765_4321   6   432198765_
98765_4321   7   32198765_4
98765_4321   8   2198765_43
98765_4321   9   198765_432
98765_4321  10   98765_4321
```

---

```
jot -w '100000000 %d' 11 0  | gawk -Mbe '($++NF = sprintf("%.*d",

     ___ = length(__ = $1), __ * 10^$2 % (10^___ - 1)))^_'

1________   0   1________
1________   1   ________1
1________   2   _______1_
1________   3   ______1__
1________   4   _____1___
1________   5   ____1____
1________   6   ___1_____
1________   7   __1______
1________   8   _1_______
1________   9   1________
1________  10   ________1
```

The same caveats for binary bit-rotation also apply here ::

1. Since the modulus is `base^power - 1` (`10^n - 1` instead of `2^n - 1`), special handling is needed for that single edge case to prevent modding down to all zeros
2. This approach is contingent upon input sizes and the # of positions to be rotated, and may require big-int libraries (if you wanna avoid doing the manual work)

---

```
jot -w '9999999999 %d' 20 0  | 

gawk -Mbe '($++NF = sprintf("%.*d %.*d %.*d %.*d",
              ___ = length(__ = $1), 
                  (____ = __ * 10^($2 % ___)) \
                        % (10^___ - 1),
              ___, ____ % (10^___ - __*___),
              ___, ____ % (10^(___ + 1) - 1),
              ___, ____ % (10^(___ - 1) - 1)))^_'

 9999999999  0   __________  9999999999   9999999999   _________9
 9999999999  1   __________  1__________  9999999999_  ________9_
 9999999999  2   __________  1________1_  999999999_9  _______9__
 9999999999  3   __________  1_______11_  99999999_99  ______9___
 9999999999  4   __________  1______111_  9999999_999  _____9____

 9999999999  5   __________  1_____1111_  999999_9999  ____9_____
 9999999999  6   __________  1____11111_  99999_99999  ___9______
 9999999999  7   __________  1___111111_  9999_999999  __9_______
 9999999999  8   __________  1__1111111_  999_9999999  _9________
 9999999999  9   __________  1_11111111_  99_99999999  _________9

 9999999999  1_  __________  9999999999   9999999999   _________9
 9999999999  11  __________  1__________  9999999999_  ________9_
 9999999999  12  __________  1________1_  999999999_9  _______9__
 9999999999  13  __________  1_______11_  99999999_99  ______9___
 9999999999  14  __________  1______111_  9999999_999  _____9____

 9999999999  15  __________  1_____1111_  999999_9999  ____9_____
 9999999999  16  __________  1____11111_  99999_99999  ___9______
 9999999999  17  __________  1___111111_  9999_999999  __9_______
 9999999999  18  __________  1__1111111_  999_9999999  _9________
 9999999999  19  __________  1_11111111_  99_99999999  _________9
```